# Selecting a max value from a pivot table

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I built a result set using a pivot table that looks like this:

```
customer  A  B  C  D
Joe.      1  4  0  2
Sue.      2  0  3  9
```

How would I select the column name with the largest value from the pivot table?  For instance:

```
Joe  B
Sue  D
```

Seems like it should be easy but I'll be damned if my skills aren't up to the task

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Sorry.  SQL 2008.  Thanks for the responses so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a giant `case` statement:

```
select customer,
       (case when A >= B and A >= C and A >= D then 'A'
             when B >= C and B >= D then 'B'
             when C >= D then 'C'
             else 'D'
        end) as MaxCol
from table t;
```

However, it would probably be much easier to do this before you pivot the data rather than afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Guess I didn't want to write the giant case statement!  There are actually quite a few more columns that I left out of the example, but this did do the trick.

Comment: @NathanCurrie if you're doing this with a lot of columns, ie 10+ or something of the like, I would use UNPIVOT since you have that option in sql server (as all you have to do is list the column names).

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you can use UNPIVOT:

**Fiddle with your data:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6601/12/0

```
select  customer, max(val)
from    (select * from tbl) x
        unpivot
        (val for col in(a, b, c, d)) y
group by customer
```